# I'm trying to import KNeihgborsClassifier from 'sklearn.neighbors'

Tags: python, web-crawler

I'm trying to import KNeihgborsClassifier from 'sklearn.neighbors' but I have this error **ImportError: cannot import name 'KNeihgborsClassifier' from 'sklearn.neighbors' (C:\Users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors_*init*_.py)**

Comment: Could it be you want to import KNeighborsClassifier (not KNei **hg** borsClassifier), spelling error?

Answer (score 0):

You are importing `KNeihgborsClassifier` which is wrong, change it to:
`from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier`